# Filter a field by the user logged

Tags: python, django

I new in Django and I have an app with three models. I need that the user create a feed, but just in its group. For example, I have 2 brands, and 2 users, one user is asignated to a brand and the other user to the other brand. When I want to create a feed with an user in the brand selection appear all the brand and I want that appear just the brand associated to the user. How can I fix that?

I have these classes

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Brand(models.Model):
"""
Brand Model
"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class UserFeed(models.Model):
"""
User feed
"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    brands = models.ManyToManyField(Brand)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.firstName

class Feed(models.Model):
"""
Principal Model for feeds and news
"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField('Date published')
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField('Date updated', auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Can you show the query that you are using to get "user in the brand selection appear the brand" (quote from question)?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from question. Maby it something like this:

```
   feed = Feed.objects.filter(barnd__in=user.brands.all())
```